# Angular2 download PDF from REST API

Tags: spring, rest, angular, filesaver.js

I have a REST API which must return a PDF. I have converted the PDF to a byte array and I return it with my REST endpoint.

The payload looks like this:

```
{"_body":"%PDF-1.4\n%����\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Catalog\n/Version /1.4\n/Pages 2 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Pages\n/Kids [3 0 R]\n/Count 1\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Page\n/MediaBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]\n/Parent 2 0 R\n/Contents 4 0 R\n/Resources 5 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 51\n>>\nstream\r\nx�s\n��w3T04R\bI�245P0\u0007�\u0014.\r�Ԝ�|�\u0000\u00177��\nM��,.�\u0010.\u0000�\u001f\n�\r\nendstream\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<<\n/Font 6 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/F1 7 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Font\n/Subtype /Type1\n/BaseFont /Courier-Bold\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 8\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000015 00000 n\r\n0000000078 00000 n\r\n0000000135 00000 n\r\n0000000247 00000 n\r\n0000000371 00000 n\r\n0000000404 00000 n\r\n0000000435 00000 n\r\ntrailer\n<<\n/Root 1 0 R\n/ID [<A0C5C7406F668B945EA55D6F36833E8A> <A0C5C7406F668B945EA55D6F36833E8A>]\n/Size 8\n>>\nstartxref\n535\n%%EOF\n","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json;charset=UTF-8"]},"type":2,"url":"http://localhost:8090/api/forms/1/submissions/1/pdf"}
```

I have imported FileSaver in my Angular2 app but I can't find a way to make it work. I need the PDF to be shown as a downloaded file on the client side when it is received. How can I do this? And should I change the way my REST endpoint returns the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *stream the data back to the client* for it to be able to download instead of sending as a byte array. Since Spring is based on servelet, you can do this like so

```
.
.
.
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    Path downloadFile = Paths.get("path/to/your/file");
    res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ downloadFile.getFileName().toString());
    OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(downloadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = -1;
    while (((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```

You might want to have error handling, I omitted just for brevity

Comment: I tried that in my endpoint. I also figured out how to save the file with Angular2. However the PDF I download is not correct, it is encoded in UTF-8 while the original PDF is encoded in ANSI. Do you think the encoding is the problem? I also tried specifying the charset to ANSI in my Spring endpoint but it doesn't support it.

Comment: @Servietsky First of all, if you can read the file without seeing funny characters, you shouldn't worry about it. Secondly, UTF-8 is a much more broader character set than ANSI, so whatever bytes are in your document, they should be decoded correctly. So all in all, don't worry about it

Comment: If I compare the two files (ANSI and UTF-8) they don't have the same characters. The "?" You can see in the payload is an actual character in the ANSI file.

Comment: I mean when you double click the file to read it, do you see funny characters? You shouldn't worry too much about the byte content of the document, as long as you don't see decoding problem, you are good

Comment: When I open the PDF from the REST API it contains an empty page without any content. The original file has some text inside it.

Comment: I fixed it, I needed to write this in my HTTP request in the frontend: `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob`. Thank you!